# fs.readFileSync only sometimes returns a valid string in specific circumstances

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, fs

In my node application, I have an `init` function:

```
function init() {
    if (!fs.existsSync("../schedule.json"))
        fs.createReadStream('../template.json').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../schedule.json'));

    var content = fs.readFileSync("../schedule.json", "utf8");

    return JSON.parse(content);
}
```

Whenever I try to run it from cmd or git bash it crashes because of the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

So I debugged it in vscode and found out that the variable `content` only contained an empty string which means that `readFileSync` is returning an empty string.

Now here is the weird thing; it never works if started in cmd or git bash (neither in regular mode or debug) or when started in debug mode in vscode but if I restart the debugger in vscode (not starting and stopping but actually hitting the restart button) then I get the correct content of the json file as a string returned from readFileSync about every other time.

Update:
I tried deleting the schedule.json file and then stepping through the code. It showed that it actually didn't enter the `if(!fs.existsSync("../schedule.json"))` statement.
It's almost like a caching bug.

Comment: Regarding your edit, if it's not entering that block it must be seeing the file as existing.  Are you sure that the relative path is correct, and you haven't maybe got another `schedule.json` somewhere around your project/working directory that may be being picked up?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I was just stupid. It seems like exress uses the root directory even though the js file was in a separate folder. So it placed the file in its grandparent directory. Still not sure why running it in hebugging worked though?

Answer (score 2):

`pipe` causes things to happen asynchronously - it's surprising that it *ever* works inside vscode, unless perhaps you're stepping through allowing `pipe` time to finish its work, or perhaps when you use restart it's seeing the file from the previous run.

Instead, you need to [wait for it to finish](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) doing what it's doing:

```
var writer = fs.createWriteStream('../schedule.json');
fs.createReadStream('../template.json').pipe(writer);
writer.on('finish', function() {
  //It's safe to read the file here
});
```

However, that's not going to work for you, since your function is expecting to work entirely synchronously and return a result.  You can make the above work if you switch to using callbacks or promises (which may or may not require a large amount of work, depending on what's going on around the call to `init`), or you can just use synchronous functions similar to what you're already using instead of `pipe`:

```
function init() {
    var templ = null;
    if (!fs.existsSync("../schedule.json")) {
        templ = fs.readFileSync("../template.json", "utf8");
        fs.writeFileSync("../schedule.json", templ, "utf8");
    }

    var content = templ != null ?
                  templ :
                  fs.readFileSync("../schedule.json", "utf8");

    return JSON.parse(content);
}
```

Comment: Although it fixes another problem (thank you very much), I'm still getting the same error as before when using the synchronous function you wrote

Comment: Have you re-verified what's in `content`?  Perhaps also inspect the contents of `template.json` and the generated `schedule.json`